# Rails a href in devise translation .yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

In my Rails 5 app I want to display custom error message if the user enters the password incorrectly for a custom strategy method. What I did is:

`devise.en.yml`

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      custom_auth: "Email is already registered. \nPlease login <a href='https://www.some_page.com'>Some Page</a> or create an account with a different email address.
```

But it won't worked, the same as:

```
custom_auth: "Email is already registered. \nPlease login [Some Page](https://www.some_page.com/login) or create an account with a different email address.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use `html_safe`, as in `I18n.t("devise.failure.custom_auth").html_safe` - otherwise the translation will be escaped, and the link will not work.

Comment: Right.. you're probably thinking about the view but I don't want to update any views because it works out of the box with devise. Is there any chance to get that without having to generate and update it directly on the view?